# how to catch missing leading zeros in ascii in java

Tags: java, binary, ascii

I have created a program that takes in a string by `Scanner` input and converts it into ASCII numbers in binary and also prints out the frequency of each letter. 
Here is my program as it is

```
import java.util.*;

public class ASCII
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence: " );
        String myString = sc.nextLine();
        int length = myString.length();
        int ascii;
        char character;
        int[] myarray = new int[256];
        for(int i =0; i < length; i++)
        {
            character = myString.charAt(i);
            ascii = (int)character; // casting the character into an int
            System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(ascii) + " ");
            myarray[ascii]++; // counting the frequency of each letter in the string
        }

        System.out.println();

        for ( int k = 0; k < myarray.length; k++ )
        {
            if ( myarray[k] > 0 ) // if the frequency is greater than 0 do this print line, without this programm would print all 255 ascii characters.
            {
                System.out.println("'"+(char)k + "'" + " appeared " +    myarray[k]      + " times." );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As we all know each ASCII should be of a length of 7 bits long but for my program it is not always the case as it is not catching the leading zeros.
For example, if I were to pass in the string "hello there"
the expected output should be

```
 "1101000 1100101 1101100 1101111 0100000 1110100 1101000 1100101 1110010   1110010 1100101"
```

but I am getting:

```
"1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110100 1101000 1100101 1110010 1100101"
```

as you can see "100000" is only 6 bits long and some of my ascii values are just wrong because of this missing leading zeros problem

I am not sure how I would go about fixing this problem and that's why I am here. If someone could show me how this could be fixed that would be great.

Comment: What is happening when you use: System.out.print(Integer.toString(ascii,2) + " ");

Comment: Yes, there are 128 ASCII codepoints numbered 0-127 and encoded as values 0-127. But, you have a few insistencies in your program based on the assumption that Java uses ASCII. Java, JavaScript, .NET, XML, HTML, … use [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). `charAt(i)` returns a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint, such as A or € or . If you want to deal with only a subset, such as the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block, you should put a guard (if-throw or similar) in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    String myString = "hello there";
    int length = myString.length();
    int ascii;
    char character;
    int[] myarray = new int[256];
    for(int i =0; i < length; i++)
    {
        character = myString.charAt(i);
        ascii = character; // casting the character into an int
        // not optimal, but works
        System.out.println(String.format("%7s", Integer.toBinaryString(ascii)).replace(' ', '0'));

        myarray[ascii]++; // counting the frequency of each letter in the string

    }
    System.out.println();

    for ( int k = 0; k < myarray.length; k++ )
    {
        if ( myarray[k] > 0 ) // if the frequency is greater than 0 do this print line, without this programm would print all 255 ascii characters.
        {
            System.out.println("'"+(char)k + "'" + " appeared " +    myarray[k]      + " times." );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using this approach it actually prints 8 bits per letter instead of 7 could you  mend it so it prints 7?

Answer (score 0):

You should either stop converting Strings to ints and compare Strings directly, or convert k to a string, append a needed quantity of leading zeroes, then convert them to chars.